# jQuery if condition for multiple .val dropdown values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm appending data to an input field depending on a drop down selection, what would be the cleanest way to do this as I have around 25 to do, at the moment I have it working like this:

```
$('#dropdown').change(function() {
  if($(this).val() == 10){
    ('#number').val('108-0<?php echo $number; ?>');
  }
});
```

Several drop down options share the same appended number so I don't want to duplicate code, I am aware I can do something like:

```
$('#dropdown').change(function() {
  if($(this).val() == 10||
     $(this).val() == 11||
     $(this).val() == 12){
    $('#number').val('108-0<?php echo $number; ?>');
}
```

But even this seems like too much, what would you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if an array of the possible values include the `.val()`:

```
$('#dropdown').change(function() {
  if ([10, 11, 12].includes(Number($(this).val()))) {
    $('#number').val('108-0<?php echo $number; ?>');
  }
});
```

No need for a big library like jQuery for something this trivial:

```
const [dropdown, number] = ['dropdown', 'number'].map(id => document.getElementById(id));
dropdown.addEventListener('change', () => {
  if ([10, 11, 12].includes(Number(dropdown.value))) {
    number.value = '108-0<?php echo $number; ?>';
  }
});
```

If you need to check multiple arrays of values, extract it into a variable first:

```
$('#dropdown').change(function() {
  const val = Number($(this).val());
  if ([10, 11, 12].includes(val)) {
    $('#number').val('108-0<?php echo $number; ?>');
  } else if ([1, 5, 15].includes(val)) {
    $('#number').val(5000);
  }
});
```

Comment: Very nice, the third one seems like the best fit but it's not working and the console isn't very helpful 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token'.

The reason for jQuery is that it's already being used elsewhere on the form so I assumed since it's already being loaded using it for this made sense?

Comment: There are no syntax errors in the code in the answer - if you have a syntax error, it's from code elsewhere (or the code was not copied verbatim). You can use jQuery if you want, but in some cases it just makes the code more bulky (eg, easier to use `elm.value` than `$(elm).val()` IMO)

Comment: Correct it was my php variable, thank you! And you're right re the JS it does look easier / cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

An array is the best way if the values don't have a pattern, but for your example, it’s better to use:

```
$('#dropdown').change(function() {
  var val = parseInt($(this).val());
  if(val >= 10 && val <= 12){
    $('#number').val('108-0<?php echo $number; ?>');
}
```